# Spring 4 @PropertySource not working when ResourceBundleMessageSource bean is registered

Tags: spring, properties, resourcebundle

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:service.properties")
public class ApplicationConfig{
    @Value("PROPERTY_MYSQL_JNDI_NAME")
    private String jndiName;
}
```

this was working fine. But when I register

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("resources/authentication");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

bean in the ApplicationConfig class previous property loading not working. is there any thing i can do to test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messageSource is wrong it should be as below assuming your authentication.properties is in src/resources:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("authentication");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

You can still use

```
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
```

Assuming config.properties is in src/resources

Comment: yes. the issue you point out is correct. Thanks. But my concern is that when i register 'messageSource' in the springContainer using @Bean ,the property file loaded by @PropertySource("classpath:service.properties") vanishes. Cannot access that propertyFile

Comment: I'm using @PageSource to load my database related properties. 

@Value(CommonConstants.PROPERTY_MYSQL_JNDI_NAME) 
private String jndiName; 

public DataSource jndiDataSource(){ 
 JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup(); 
 dsLookup.setResourceRef(true); 
 DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource(jndiName); 
 return dataSource; 
}

 --- Is there any way to achive this. –

Comment: @shak Sorry ignore my previous comment I have tested again and it works with both, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. In my case, I had missed adding the following bean:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

which made the property loading work correctly.